# How to set a timeout on a soap call using ksoap2-android?

Tags: android, soap, timeout, ksoap2, httpconnection

I'm using [ksoap2](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) for my android project and it works great. I've succeeded in connecting to distant server but I currently have a problem when I want to set a timeout to my androidhttptransport.

Is there a clean way (maybe an attribute to set?) to deal with it?

I've found this same question [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473810/how-do-i-enforce-a-timeout-on-a-webservice-call-using-ksoap-2) but it's not very detailed. Does someone have any detailed answer to this problem?

Thanks in advance for help!

Romain

Comment: Ok I did what ZZ Coder said on the other thread. I'm not sure if it's the neatest way to deal with connection exception but it works. Let's say you have an event to launch your soap request. Then do it in a new thread and build a timer to watch it. I can post code if you need. Cheers ;)

Comment: Found a more elegant way to test connection! it's written there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this thread: [KSoap Request Timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408955/ksoap-request-timeout)