# KSoap Request Timeout?

Tags: android-ksoap2

friends,

i dont see request timeout in KSoap library

any one guide me what should i do? 
or from where to download latest version of it?

my code

```
 SoapObject userRequest=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
                userRequest.addProperty("session_id", session_id ); 
                userRequest.addProperty("page_size", PageSize); 
                userRequest.addProperty("offset",Offset ); 


                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
                request.addProperty("GetAlertsInput", userRequest); 


                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new 
SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
                envelope.bodyOut = request; 


                HttpTransportAndroid androidHttpTransport = new 
HttpTransportAndroid(URL); 


 androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_GETALERTS, envelope);
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could mention that I made a modification to the KSoap2 v2.5.2 to support timeout for HttpTransportSE class. It will throw a SocketTimeoutException when timeout occurs.

It's both jar and src is found at this url https://www.lightsoftai.com/?p=707

Comment: link is not longer valid

Answer (score 0):

I have more than one methods on  the server . I am using the same line

```
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_GETALERTS, envelope);
```

With different methods name, while getting second response its crashing.

Answer (score 0):

STEP : 1
Get the ksoap2-android-assembly-3.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar file. And place the jar file in app > libs folder.

STEP : 2
compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar') place the line in build gradle > dependencies.

STEP :3
static int networkTimeOut = 60 * 1000;

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(inserttransaction_request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, networkTimeOut);
```