# ksoap2 issue java.net.ConnectException

Tags: android, ksoap

I am using kSoap2 for accessing soap web services. I am getting **java.net.connectException** while executing the below line

```
androidHttpTransport.call(Constants.SOAP_ACTION_GET_METHOD_NAME, envelope)
```

This is not happening always, but some of the times. Is this the problem with connection time out to the server? How to increase the connection time out in kSoap ? I googled, but can't find out the solution .
Can anyone suggest me the solution to fix this error.

Logcat details follows:

```
07-17 14:46:24.800: W/System.err(8103): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to www.yahoo.com/175.41.138.237 (port 80) after 20000ms: isConnected failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
07-17 14:46:24.800: W/System.err(8103):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:214)
07-17 14:46:24.800: W/System.err(8103):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:152)
07-17 14:46:24.800: W/System.err(8103):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
07-17 14:46:24.800: W/System.err(8103):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
07-17 14:46:24.800: W/System.err(8103):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
07-17 14:46:24.800: W/System.err(8103):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
07-17 14:46:24.800: W/System.err(8103):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:77)
07-17 14:46:24.800: W/System.err(8103):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
07-17 14:46:24.800: W/System.err(8103):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
07-17 14:46:24.800: W/System.err(8103):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
07-17 14:46:24.810: W/System.err(8103):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
07-17 14:46:24.810: W/System.err(8103):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
07-17 14:46:24.810: W/System.err(8103):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
07-17 14:46:24.810: W/System.err(8103):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
07-17 14:46:24.810: W/System.err(8103):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
07-17 14:46:24.810: W/System.err(8103):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
07-17 14:46:24.810: W/System.err(8103):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:80)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to increase the connection time out in kSoap ?

There still seems to be an open issue with `HttpTransportSE` ignoring the timeout value in some situations. 
See this related [link](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=60&q=httpTransportse%20timeout).

However, a solution for this involved modification of the existing `ksoap2 API`.

Thanks to the developers at [Lightsoftai](http://www.lightsoftai.com/?p=707) you can now add timeout to `HttpTransportSE` using the following code:

**Note** : *You can use ksoap2 API version 2.5.2 or greater for this*

```
       /**
       * Creates instance of HttpTransportSE with set url
       *
       * @param url 
       *             the destination to POST SOAP data
       */
         public HttpTransportSE(String url) {
         super(url);
         }

       /**
      * Creates instance of HttpTransportSE with set url
      *
      * @param url
      *            the destination to POST SOAP data
      * @param timeout
      *               timeout for connection and Read Timeouts (milliseconds)
       */
       public HttpTransportSE(String url, int timeout) {
       super(url, timeout);
          }
```

You can download the jar file for the same from [here](http://www.lightsoft.se/_lightsoft/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=1).

Also refer [ksoap never timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489671/ksoap-never-timeout).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes . Your solution helped me. As u said, i changed to new version of ksoap now. Now that java.net.ConnectException is not coming . But i am getting java.net.SocketTimeOutException now.

Comment: yes that will come, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408955/ksoap-request-timeout)...try to catch it and that should solve the problem. Also, you can try: HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,60000);HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,60000);

Comment: Yes i am using the same already, HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Constants.URL,30000); But only 30 ms. whether 60 ms will help me

Comment: yes. difference is there. previously it will come 7 out of 10 times . Now 4 out of 10 times. If u find any other solution , Pls share with me .